# R - group data frame from a variable

Tags: r, dplyr, group-summaries

I want to set the column for grouping a data frame into a variable and then group and summarise the data frame based on it, i.e.

```
require(dplyr)
var <- colnames(mtcars)[10]
summaries <- mtcars %>% dplyr::group_by(var) %>% dplyr::summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

such that I can simply change `var` and use the second line without changing anything. Unfortunately my solution does not work as `group_by` asks the column name and not a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group_by_`, which takes arguments as character strings:

```
require(dplyr)
var <- colnames(mtcars)[10]
summaries <- mtcars %>% dplyr::group_by_(var) %>% dplyr::summarise_each(funs(mean))
```

(Maybe resources on standard vs non-standard evaluation would be of interest: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)

Comment: thanks a lot! now I realize it was really a silly question...